# Python openpyxl How to SET the active or selected cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

In Python with openpyxl I'd like to change the active cell when the user opens the spreadsheet.

This produces 'A1':

```
 print("Active Cell: " + WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell)
```

This produces an error when the file is opened (Corrupted file):

```
 WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'A4'
```

How can I set the active/selected cell to something other than A1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For openpyxls version 2.3.2 I got this to work:

```
 WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'A4'
 WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = 'A4'
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is for an older version of the library that is no longer supported. You should link to the correct anwser.

Comment: @CharlieClark - which is the correct answer? Another answer to this question doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried this answer, and it seems to work in the current version (I have 3.0.3).

Comment: This answer worked for me in Version 3.0.9 @CharlieClark if this answer is wrong, please provide the correct answer with a working example or link to the documentation where the correct answer example is.

Comment: In my case `WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection` was of length 2, and it only worked when I changed the last index, like so: `WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[-1].activeCell = 'A4';  WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[-1].sqref = 'A4'`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer and the answer by BryanSJT, I created this loop which should set all selections correctly to A1

```
for selection in ws.views.sheetView[0].selection:
        selection.activeCell = "A1"
        selection.sqref = "A1"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you got openpyxl version 2.5.4 or later, try typing below to set active cell

```
ws.cell(row=4, column=1)
wb.save("spreadsheet.xlsx")
```

assume ws is the worksheet you use, and you want to set cell A4 active. Make sure you save the spreadsheet in your code.

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work in version 3.0.9, still looking for an answer to this problem

Comment: I would be surprised if this worked, as `ws.cell(...)` just reads from a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using openpyxl version 3.0.7 and found that for an excel file I have it was necessary to also do the same definition for selection[1].

```
worksheet.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell = 'A1'
worksheet.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].sqref = 'A1'

worksheet.views.sheetView[0].selection[1].activeCell = 'A1'
worksheet.views.sheetView[0].selection[1].sqref = 'A1'
```

or

```
data_sheet.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'A1'
data_sheet.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = 'A1'

data_sheet.sheet_view.selection[1].activeCell = 'A1'
data_sheet.sheet_view.selection[1].sqref = 'A1'
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

With openpyxl 3.0.10 and an XLSX file I found it was enough to set `sqref` on `selection[0]`:

```py
wb["Sheet 1"].views.sheetView[0].selection[0].sqref = "A1"
wb["Sheet 2"].views.sheetView[0].selection[0].sqref = "B2"
wb["Sheet 3"].views.sheetView[0].selection[0].sqref = "C3"
```

Setting `activeCell` didn't seem to have an effect.